# iOS how to use delegate method from within block

Tags: ios, delegates, scope, objective-c-blocks

I am using AFNetworking for request/response tasks of my application. In one of my handler classes, when an HTTP request succeeds, I must perform a call to delegate method in order to update the UI (note that I specifically do not want to use NSNotificationCenter). However, the compiler complains about the delegate not being declared. I must keep overlooking it somehow and make the same mistake. Here is the simple version of my problematic code:

```
//MYHandler.h
@protocol MYDelegate <NSObject>
-(void) myDelegateMethod;
@end

@interface MYHandler : NSObject
@property (strong, nonatomic) id<MYDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

---

```
//MYHandler.m
@implementation MYHandler
    -(void) doSomething
    {
        //Create and configure request
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: successBlock failure:failureBlock];
        [operation start];
    }

    //Success and Failure
    typedef void(^SuccessBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject);
    typedef void(^FailureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error);

    SuccessBlock successBlock = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [_delegate myDelegateMethod];
        //^this says _delegate is an undeclared identifier
    };
    FailureBlock failureBlock = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    };
@end
```

---

```
//MyViewController.h
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <MYDelegate>

@end
```

---

```
//MyViewController.m
-(void) myDelegateMethod
{
    //
}
```

Comment: I've tried pretty much everything and i can't manage to run into your error.
In your code, Is your protocol declared in a separate file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are outside of any method. It's like you're trying to do this:

```
//MYHandler.m
@implementation MYHandler
    -(void) doSomething
    {
        //Create and configure request
        AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
        operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: successBlock failure:failureBlock];
        [operation start];
    }

    [_delegate myDelegateMethod];

@end
```

Clearly this won't work.

You could instead create methods that return those blocks:

```
@implementation MYHandler

typedef void(^SuccessBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject);
typedef void(^FailureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error);

- (void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject))success
{
    return ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [_delegate myDelegateMethod];
    };
}

- (void(^)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error))failure
{
    return ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    };
}

-(void) doSomething
{
    SuccessBlock successBlock = [self success];
    FailureBlock failureBlock = [self failure];
    //Create and configure request
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: successBlock failure:failureBlock];
    [operation start];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the delegate variable from outside the scope of the class. Try this:

```
//MYHandler.m
-(void) doSomething
{
    //Success and Failure
    typedef void(^SuccessBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject);
    typedef void(^FailureBlock)(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error);

    SuccessBlock successBlock = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
        [_delegate myDelegateMethod];
        //^this says _delegate is an undeclared identifier
    };
    FailureBlock failureBlock = ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"%@", error);
    };

    //Create and configure request
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];
    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess: successBlock failure:failureBlock];
    [operation start];
}
```

Comment: I am not sure about this as I first moved the declaration of success and failure to enhance readability of the code. Also, they are not outside of MYHandler implementation, only outside of the `doSomething` method declaration. Is there any other way that I can make it access the `self`s scope?

Comment: Added another answer with some examples. Hope they help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case the parameter you call `_delegate` is not in the scope and can not be used at all. To solve this you might want to declare the block itself where this parameter is in the scope. For instance declare it in the method where you pass the block to the request method.

Since this procedure is actually more common then yours where you declare the block outside the class implementation I can assume there is a reason you moved it outside. If this is for some reason mandatory you could use a macro `#define successBlock ^(AFHTTPRequestOperation...` which will at compile time insert the code for you. Doing so will insert the scope where you use the block as well.

Why this happens is you need to think of block just the same as C/C++ functions, if you want to use the `_delegate` you also need to insert it as an input parameter next to `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject` in one of your cases.

Why this actually works without an explicit parameter declaration is because the compiler already kind of does that for you but still, it does need that object to be in the scope.

Comment: There is a misunderstanding, they are not outside of class implementation, only outside of the `doSomething` method declaration.

Comment: This is still the same, if a delegate is an instance parameter it is not in the scope of a static part of the class. If for instance you create a static method such as +(void)foo; you again can not use your delegate parameter inside that method...

Comment: Thank you @Matic. Darn quick lessons, they don't even teach you the basics. I did not know about the static part of the class. I thought unless I mark something as static or class method it would be dynamic and in the instance scope. You have cleared so many things for me.